# How define is Excel cell partially visible ?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, vba

Is it possible to use Excel interop to define is some cell visible partially ?

[image]

I know that using [Application.ActiveWindow.VisibleRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198311.aspx) I can get visible range of sheet. 
This cell at row 46 included in this range, but do we have some method to define is individual cell visible partially only ?

Our add-in inserts some text into cell. My task is scroll a bit selected cell to make it completely visible. If I double click in such cell in Excel, cursor will appear over there and sheet is scrolled a bit, I want do the same with C# code.
So far I found way to define cases when user works with last row (by using  `Application.ActiveWindow.VisibleRange` and scrolling with [Application.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839921.aspx)), but I can't guarantee that last row always partially visible - I don't need to scroll completely visible cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make the last cell in the range partially visible by using `Application.Goto` to bring the cell to the top of the page and then paging up using `ActiveWindow.LargeScroll`

```
Sub MakeLastCellPartiallyVisible(rCell As Range)
    Dim lastVRow As Long
    lastVRow = rCell.Row + rCell.Rows.Count - 1
    Application.Goto Reference:=Rows(lastVRow), Scroll:=True
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll Down:=-1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Eventually I found way to fix my task, the approach I used very similar to yours. However, I don't quite understand why  "The last visible row is always partially visible", do you have any reference to some doc ? I understand that 1 pixel can make cell partially visible, but probably, we can meet case, when there is no any partially visible cell and visible range fits whole working view of workbook.

Comment: You are correct, it's not always visible.  I removed that part of the post. I will try and fix that function and re-post it.

Answer (score 0):

My goal was scroll partially visible cell in order to see entire cell. If my code inserting some value into `A46` cell (in question) I need to scroll it a bit down to see entire cell.
The method in C#:

```
public void MakeCellVisible(int columnIndex, int rowIndex)
{
    var visibleRange = Application.ActiveWindow.VisibleRange;
    var lastColumn = visibleRange.Column + visibleRange.Columns.Count - 1;
    var lastRow = visibleRange.Row + visibleRange.Rows.Count - 1;

    int down, toRight;
    if (rowIndex == lastRow)
    {
        down = 1;
    }

    if (columnIndex == lastColumn)
    {
        toRight = 1;
    }

    if (0 != down || 0 != toRight)
    {
        Application.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll(Down: down, ToRight: toRight);
    }
}
```